# SystemError: <built-in function TF_Run> returned a result with an error set

Tags: python, tensorflow

I want to implement NER task with TensorFlow, so I divided the conll2003 corpus
into train_set and valid_set, and the train_set and valid_set has the same format. The I run the code below on train_set(in the code it is called train_reader )

```
    from __future__ import absolute_import
    from __future__ import division
    from __future__ import print_function

    import tensorflow as tf
    import numpy as np
    from nlpfromscratch.vocab import  MultiVocab
    from nlpfromscratch.csvreader import CSVReader
    from nlpfromscratch.embeds import Embeddings
    from nlpfromscratch.mlp import linear
    from nlpfromscratch.loss import reg_softmax_loss
    from nlpfromscratch.args import parser
    from nlpfromscratch.convnet import conv_max
    from nlpfromscratch.evaluation import metrics, prf_eval
    import os 

    train_path = "E:\\github\\nlpfromscratch-tf\\data\\conll2003\\train_ner_w3.csv"
    valid_path = "E:\\github\\nlpfromscratch-tf\\data\\conll2003\\valid_ner_w3.csv"
    log_dir = "E:\\github\\nlpfromscratch-tf\\data\\conll2003\\"
    batch_size = 32
    vocab_path = "E:\\github\\nlpfromscratch-tf\\data\\conll2003\\vocab.json"
    word_dim = 50
    feat_dim = 8
    n_hidden = 300
    lambda_ = 0.001
    init = 0.01
    max_epochs = 20

    train_reader = CSVReader(train_path, batch_size) #read the data
    valid_reader = CSVReader(valid_path, batch_size) 
    seq_len = train_reader.seq_len
    num_feats = train_reader.num_feats

    chkpt = os.path.join(log_dir, 'nlpfromscratch')

    with tf.Graph().as_default():

        sess = tf.Session()
        global_step = tf.contrib.framework.get_or_create_global_step()

        tokens_pl = tf.placeholder(tf.string, (batch_size, seq_len))
        features_pl = tf.placeholder(tf.string, (batch_size, seq_len, num_feats))
        labels_pl = tf.placeholder(tf.string, (batch_size, ))

        multi_vocab = MultiVocab(vocab_path)
        label_lookup = multi_vocab.labels.lookup(labels_pl)
        metrics(multi_vocab._labels)

        embeddings = Embeddings(multi_vocab, word_dim, feat_dim, num_feats)
        encoded_input = embeddings.encode(tokens_pl, features_pl)

        wx_plus_b = linear(encoded_input, n_hidden, 'hidden', lambda_)
        hidden = tf.nn.relu(wx_plus_b)
        logits = linear(hidden, multi_vocab.num_classes, 'classify', lambda_)

        with tf.name_scope('predict'):
            predict = multi_vocab.labels_inv.lookup(
            tf.argmax(tf.nn.softmax(logits), axis=1))

        loss = reg_softmax_loss(logits, label_lookup)
        grad = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(init)
        train_op = grad.minimize(loss,global_step = global_step)


        summary = tf.summary.merge_all()
        summary_writer = tf.summary.FileWriter(log_dir, sess.graph)
        embeddings.embed_visualization(summary_writer, log_dir, vocab_path)

        saver = tf.train.Saver( )

        sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
        sess.run(tf.tables_initializer())

        for tokens, features, labels in train_reader.batcher(max_epochs):

            feed_dict = {tokens_pl:tokens, features_pl:features, labels_pl:labels}
            summ, step_loss, gs, _ =sess.run([summary, loss, global_step, train_op],
                                     feed_dict=feed_dict)
            if gs % 10 == 0:
                print(gs, train_reader.epoch, max_epochs, step_loss)
```

it had no problem at all.But when I changed the train_set into valid_set.

```
    predict = multi_vocab.labels_inv.lookup(tf.argmax(tf.nn.softmax(logits), axis=1))        
    for tokens, features, truths, in valid_reader.batcher(1): # only one epoch for validation
        feed_dict = {tokens_pl:tokens, features_pl:features}
        predictions = sess.run(predict, feed_dict=feed_dict)
```

it went wrong and returned:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<ipython-input-21-a79489f6e284>", line 1, in <module>
        runfile('E:/github/nlpfromscratch-tf/train.py',wdir='E:/github/nlpfromscratch-tf')
        File "F:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py", line 714, in runfile
execfile(filename, namespace)
        File "F:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py", line 89, in execfile
exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)
        File "E:/github/nlpfromscratch-tf/train.py", line 97, in <module>
features_pl)
        File "E:\github\nlpfromscratch-tf\nlpfromscratch\evaluation.py", line 35, in prf_eval
predictions = sess.run(predict, feed_dict=feed_dict)
        File "F:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 767, in run
run_metadata_ptr)
        File "F:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 965, in _run
feed_dict_string, options, run_metadata)
        File "F:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1015, in _do_run
target_list, options, run_metadata)
        File "F:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1022, in _do_call
return fn(*args)
        File "F:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1004, in _run_fn
status, run_metadata)

    SystemError: <built-in function TF_Run> returned a result with an error set
```

First I thought it maybe wrong with my code for validation. So I used the valid_set for training like this:

```
   for tokens, features, labels in valid_reader.batcher(max_epochs):

    feed_dict = {tokens_pl:tokens, features_pl:features, labels_pl:labels}
    summ, step_loss, gs, _ =sess.run([summary, loss, global_step, train_op],
                                     feed_dict=feed_dict)
```

It returned the same error! **So I am quite confused why the the train_set has no problems but the valid_set goes wrong when they has total the same format.**

Comment: Can you show a bit more of your code?

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I have added more detail of my code.

Comment: Maybe some data in validation set is corrupted/invalid. Could you try reduce the validation set it to just a single sample, which you know is valid?